# How to do two-way data binding in DevExtreme tag box

Tags: angular, devextreme, two-way

I use DevExtreme in my project. I would like to do two-way data binding in dx-tag-box.  I use below syntax. But it throws an error, can somebody help.

```
<dx-tag-box [items]="sampleProducts" [(ngModel)]="[sampleProducts[0]]"></dx-tag-box>
```

Comment: What exactly error did you get?

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 27 in [[sampleProducts[0]]=$event] in BmiComponent@218:59 ("            <div class="dx-field-value">
                        <dx-tag-box [items]="sampleProducts" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="[sampleProducts[0]]"></dx-tag-box>
                        <"): BmiComponent@218:59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I suggest you use the `value` option instead of `ngModel`:

```
<dx-tag-box
    [items]="simpleProducts"
    [(value)]="values"
</dx-tag-box>
```

Do not forget to set the `values` array in your `component.ts` file:

```
export class AppComponent {
    simpleProducts: string[];
    //...
    constructor(service: Service) {
        //...
        this.simpleProducts = service.getSimpleProducts();
        this.values = [this.simpleProducts[0]];
    }
}
```